# read message from message queue in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, message-queue

I want to connect to my active message queue in node js
this code is connecting to the queue, but the question is how to subscribe to a particular queue?

```
   let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:61614', 'stomp')

    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log('opening...')
        ws.send('CONNECT\n\n\0')
    }

    ws.onclose = () => console.log('closing...')
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        if (e.data.startsWith('MESSAGE')) {
            console.log(e.data)
        }

    }
```

any suggeestion can be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the problem out
the problem was in this line startsWith('MESSAGE'))
it should be startsWith(''))

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Developer Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) there is no 'particular' queue. See how to connect:

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```